# Entity Framework - Automatically Adding Unattached Items

Tags: entity-framework

I use EF 5 and Code First.

Ive got a main ViewModel that exposes a Translation Property. A Translation consists out of 1 to n Translation Items. The Translation Property is bound to a Usercontrol. When the Translation is created and Added via _context.Translations.Add(t) in the Viewmodel also all TranslationItems inside the Translation are saved and stored correctly in the DB.

But when i try to Add a new TranslationItem (t.TranslationItems.Add) to a existing Translation it isn't saved in the DB. context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added) also returns no elements so i guess the new Translation Items is still unattached. Since the TranslationItem is added inside the Child Usercontrol, i can't access the current Datacontext To set the Entity State to Added.

What can i do?

Edit:

```
public class Translation : BaseEntity, IValidatableObject
{

    private List<TranslationItem> _translations;
         public virtual List<TranslationItem> Translations
    { 
        get{
            return _translations;
        }
        set
        {
            _translations = value;

        }
    }s
```

In ViewModel:

```
Translation = new Translation(); or

Translation = repo.GetTranslation(1);
```

Binding to custom Usercontrol:

```
<Views:TranslationTextInput   Translations="{Binding Translation}"/>
```

In code behind of UserControl:

```
             Trans.Translations.Add(new TranslationItem() { Text = "", Lcid = new CultureInfo("en").LCID });
```

Save function:

```
    public void Update(Translation t)
    {
        if (t.Id == 0)
            _context.Units.Add(t);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I create the Context in the Viewmodel Constructor and pass it to the repository class.

Comment: Can you post your code you're using to add a TranslationItem to the Translation?  I think the root of your problem is that the Translation itself is unattached - how is are you creating the Translation?  I'd start with attaching the Translation whenever you originally created it, if you can.

Comment: Does your code work when you do: Translation = repo.GetTranslation(1); since you're getting an existing Translation from a context?  If so, Just attach the Translation to your context when you create it in the viewmodel, or create a repo.CreateTranslation that will create and attach at once

Comment: If i edit existing TranslationItems and save them, they are stored correctly in the db. When adding new Translation Items it isn't working.

Comment: Do you see the Translation itself in your ChangeTracker when you're running the update code, to be sure the Translation is being tracked? Your update code is only adding it if it's new.  If not, you should attach the translation.  If your translation is being tracked - can you create a repo function to create the TranslationItem and attach the TranslationItem rather than creating one in a detached state?

Comment: The Translation is tracked. But how can i create a new attached Translation inside the child usercontrol without passing the Datacontext from outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ChangeTracker **should** automatically grab all it's children if the `Translation` is properly attached. However, you could try attaching all of the `TranslationItems` inside the `Translation` if you're sure that the `Translation` is attached to the context.

I'm not sure of the `DbSet` name for `TranslationItems`, change that to whatever you named it.

```
public void Update(Translation t)
{
    if (t.Id == 0)
        _context.Units.Add(t);

    foreach (var ti in t.Translations)
    {
         if (_context.Entry(ti).State == EntityState.Detached)
         {
             _context.TranslationItems.Attach(ti);
         }
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```